# Value Error thrown when subtracting 2 datetime values in Numpy np.where clause

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is the data:

```
id,max,min
1234,2020-06-02 00:48:40,2021-01-08 21:28:00
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
df_input = pd.read_csv("sample.csv") 
df_input["activity_end_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df_input['max'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', errors='coerce')
df_input["yesterday"] = datetime.now

df_input["quit"] = np.where(((df_input["yesterday"]-df_input["activity_end_datetime"]) > pd.Timedelta(14), 1, 0))
```

Why is this np.where comparison throwing a Value error?

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How do I make sense of this error?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data frame so that others can better help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need `np.where`

```
m = (df_input["yesterday"]-df_input["activity_end_datetime"]) > pd.Timedelta(14)
df['new'] = m.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks like one pair too many parenthesis:

```
np.where(((df_input["yesterday"]-df_input["activity_end_datetime"]) > pd.Timedelta(14), 1, 0))
         ^
```

Try breaking your code down:

```
cond = (df_input["yesterday"]-df_input["activity_end_datetime"]) > pd.Timedelta(14)

df_input["quit"] = np.where(cond, 1, 0)
# or
# df_input['quit'] = cond.astype(int)
```